# Unrecognized status byte in Midi file

Tags: midi, smf

I've been working on Midi file for some time and I stuck on some kind of status byte of thing. According to the standard Midi file format there is no such a things. So, Can someone tell what is this 3 bytes information "**00 a040**". I know that "**00**" is the byte stands for delta time and 0xa0 should be status byte, If only I understood it correctly. Last 3 bytes located at line 18 is the only part I don't understand so far. After those 3 bytes, then comes the text meta event bytes lead by "**00 ff01**".

Midi File Line 18th to 19th:

```
ff 51 03 09 cc 90 00 c0 00 00 b0 07 64 00 0a 40  
00 ff 01 20 62 64 63 61 34 32 36 64 31 30 34 61
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SMF specification](https://www.midi.org/specifications/item/standard-midi-files-smf) says:

> Running status is used: status bytes of MIDI channel messages may be omitted if the preceding event is a MIDI channel message with the same status.

So these bytes can be decoded as follows:

`ff 51 03 09 cc 90`: meta event: set tempo, 9CC90h = 642192 µs per quarter note
`00`: delta time
`c0 00`: set program 0 (piano) on channel 0
`00`: delta time
`b0 07 64`: set controller 7 (volumn) to value 100
`00`: delta time
   `0a 40`: running status (repeat B0h); set controller 10 (expression) to value 64
`00`: delta time
`ff 01 20 ...`: meta event: text: "bdca426d104a..."

Comment: Now I see. I was so confused on those bytes. So, if channel message with the same status as previous one would written without a status byte. Thanks!